# Algebra question: Do composite functions remain odd/even

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

“If $g$ is an even function and $h$ = $ ∘$, then $h$ is also an even function.”

So tried it with one even function, $g(x)=x^2-5$ and an odd function and $f(x)=5x$  $$f(g(x))=f(g(-x))=25x^2-5$$

Will $h(x)$ always be even an function so long as $g(x)$ is an even function?

Comment: Hint: h(x) = f(g(x)). What is h(-x)?

Comment: It is f(g(-x)). My bad for not being clear enough. I am asking a separate question whether this will always be the case for any even function g(x) though.

Comment: The reason I wrote hint was so that you would think about what h(-x) is, and then hopefully arrive at the computation done by Glacier below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $g$ is an even function, then $g(x)=g(-x)$. Taking images,
$$h(x)=f(g(x))=f(g(-x))=h(-x).$$ Thus, the composite function $h=f\circ g$ is also even.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I wasn't clear enough on my question. I edited it now, I meant to ask whether this will be true so long as g(x) is an even function?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. What I presented was a formal proof. But you can test it on any function you like. Applying to your function of $g(x)=x^2-5$, $$g(x)=x^2-5=(-x)^2-5=g(-x)$$ Thus, $$f(g(x))=f(x^2-5)=25x^2-5=25(-x)^2-5=f((-x)^2-5)=f(g(-x))$$